# ABEM adding modifiers directly to an element?

Tags: css, bem

I'm beginning to learn more about CSS formatting and now I've picked up ABEM to use along with SCSS to develop a WordPress site.

Is it then valid to add a modifier directly to let's say an `h1` block? Like this:

HTML

```
<h1 class="-green">To make the text green.</h1>
```

CSS

```
.-green {
 color: green;
}
```

Or do I need to add a block or an element before to modify it instead?
Like this:

HTML

```
<h1 class="a-heading_text -green">To make the text green.</h1>
```

CSS

```
.a-heading_text.-green {
 color: green;
}
```

Comment: Ah no, the modifier floats on its own. This is so you don't need to write out the block element before, and then just use the modifier on its own. Like to centre stuff instead of saying ```a-heading_text-green``` you can just use the modifier ```-green``` on it. But yeah I think I just answered my own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ABEM is a BEM variant and a lonely modifier wouldn't be BEM-compliant. Your second option is the right one: you *"need to add a block or an element before to modify it instead"*.

If you want to create a standalone helper for a simple purpose, then it is not a modifier but a block:

```
<h1 class="green">To make the text green.</h1>
```

With the CSS:

```
.green {
  color: green;
}
```

This helper block can of course be [mixed](https://en.bem.info/methodology/quick-start/#mix) with other blocks or elements. The following code is valid:

```
<h1 class="a-heading_text green">To make the heading text green.</h1>
```

Comment: Ah okay so if it has no other block or element in front of it and I need it to turn ex. green then It becomes a block, because a modifier can't be on its own in an elements class right?